# React is rendering blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Below is my code of router and view , I have also tried to return just normal text from view ,still it is not getting rendered.

Router.js

```
    require('../../utils/ensure-https.js');
    import styles from '../../../static/stylesheets/app/dashboard.css';
    import {Header} from '../common/header-view.js';
    import DashBoardView from './components/dashboard-view.js';
    import UserInformationView from './components/user-information-view.js';

    var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
    var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
    var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
    var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

    var wrapComponent = function(Component, props) {
      return React.createClass({
        render() {
          return React.createElement(Component, props);
        }
      });
    };

    var routes = (
        <Router history={ReactRouter.browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component = {wrapComponent(Header,{activeTab: 'dashboard'})}>
            <IndexRoute component={DashBoardView}/>
            <Route path="/user-information" component = {UserInformationView}/>
          </Route>
        </Router>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("wrapper"));
```

dashboard-view.js

```
            import {latas} from '../../common/header-view.js';
            import ClassSet from '../../../mixins/class-set-mixin.js';

            var DashBoardView = React.createClass({
                    mixins: [ReactRouter.Navigation, ClassSet],
                    render: function() {
                            return (
                               <div>
                               <div className={socketDisconnectClass}>
                               <p>Socket has been disconnected. Please refresh or click                     <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.reloadDashboard}>here</a> </p>
                               </div></div>
                           );
                    } });
       export default DashBoardView;
```

Header-view.js

```
            import ClassSet from '../../mixins/class-set-mixin.js';
            import SessionStore from '../../stores/SessionStore.js';
            import InterruptionStore from '../../stores/InterruptionStore.js';
            import Authorization from '../../mixins/access-mixin.js';
            import DateFormatterMixin from '../../mixins/date-formatter-mixin.js';
            import CommonActions from '../../mixins/common-mixin.js';
            import MapLayers from '../common/map-layers-view.js';

            var latas = {};


            var Header = React.createClass({
                mixins: [ReactRouter.Navigation, ClassSet, Authorization, DateFormatterMixin, CommonActions],

                getDefaultProps: function() {
                    return {
                        activeTab: 'dashboard'
                    };
                },

                getInitialState: function() {
                    return {
                        displayUserMenu: false,
                        toggleMenu: false,
                        displayAdminMenu: false,
                        toggleAdminMenu: false,
                        notifications: [],
                        map: null
                    };
                },

                goToUserProfile: function() {
                    location.href='dashboard.html#/user-information'
                },

                goToApiDoc: function () {
                    location.href='/apiDocumentation.html'
                },

                gotoPrivacyPolicy: function () {
                    window.open('dashboard.html#/privacypolicy', '_newtab')
                },

                goToApiUsers: function () {
                    location.href='userManagement.html#/api-userlisting'
                },
                componentWillMount: function() {
                    this.access_token = SessionStore.getAccessToken();
                    if(!this.access_token) {
                        location.href = '/';
                    } else {
                        this.canAccess = this.checkForAccess();
                        if(!this.canAccess) {
                            location.href = '/dashboard.html';
                        }
                    }
                    latas.setMap = function(map, flightCallback) {
                        this.setState({
                            map: map,
                            toggleFlightLayer: flightCallback
                        });
                    }.bind(this);
                    latas.setLayersViewState = function() {
                        this.refs.mapLayers.setState(this.refs.mapLayers.state);
                    }.bind(this)
                },

                isValidIe: function () {
                    if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1]) <= 9) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                },

                checkForAccess: function() {
                    var canAccess = true;
                    var activeTab = this.props.activeTab;
                    if(activeTab === 'geofence') {
                        canAccess = this.canAccessGeofenceManagement();
                    }
                    else if(activeTab === 'user') {
                        canAccess = this.canAccessUserManagement();
                    }
                    else if(activeTab === 'user') {
                        canAccess = this.canAccessApiUserManagement();
                    }
                    return canAccess;
                },

                componentWillUnmount: function() {
                    $(window).unbind('scroll');
                },

                componentDidMount: function() {
                    latas.setNotification = function(notifications) {
                        this.setState({
                            notifications: notifications
                        });
                    }.bind(this);
                },

                showMenu: function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var displayUserMenu = this.state.displayUserMenu;
                    this.setState({
                        displayUserMenu: !displayUserMenu,
                        displayNotificationMenu: false,
                        displayAdminMenu: false,
                        toggleMenu: !this.state.toggleMenu
                    });
                },

                showAdminMenu: function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var displayAdminMenu = this.state.displayAdminMenu;
                    this.setState({
                        displayAdminMenu: !displayAdminMenu,
                        displayNotificationMenu: false,
                        displayUserMenu: false,
                        toggleAdminMenu: !this.state.toggleAdminMenu
                    });
                },

                gotoNotifications: function(e) {
                    this.transitionTo('notification');
                },

                showNotifications: function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var displayNotificationMenu = this.state.displayNotificationMenu;
                    this.setState({
                        displayNotificationMenu: !displayNotificationMenu,
                        displayUserMenu: false,
                        displayAdminMenu: false
                    });
                },

                logOutUser: function() {
                    SessionStore.removeUserSession();
                    InterruptionStore.removeUserInterruption();
                    location.href = '/';
                },

                resetDropdown: function() {
                    this.setState({
                        displayNotificationMenu: false,
                        displayUserMenu: false,
                        toggleMenu: false,
                        toggleAdminMenu: false,
                        displayAdminMenu: false
                    });
                },

                getNotifications: function() {
                  var notificationArray = _.values(this.state.notifications);
                  notificationArray.sort(function(notification1, notification2) {
                    return notification2.time - notification1.time;
                  });
                    return _.map(notificationArray, function(notification) {
                      var notificationTime = this.formatTimeTohhmmtt(new Date(notification.time));
                        var iconClassDrone = notification.notificationType === 1 ? 'icon-droneAlert pull-left' : 'icon-lowBattery pull-left';
                        var iconClassWarning = notification.notificationType === 1 ? 'icon-alert pull-left' : 'icon-alertBattery pull-left';
                        var messageClass = notification.notificationType === 1 ? 'dangerZone' : 'batteryLow';
                        return (
                            <li className="clearfix new">
                              <i className={iconClassDrone}></i>
                              <div className="droneNameId pull-left">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);">{notification.droneName}</a>
                                <span className="droneIds clearfix"><span className="notifyHeaderIdDrone pull-left">ID :</span><span className="notifyHeaderDroneId pull-left">{notification.droneId}</span></span>
                              </div>
                              <i className={iconClassWarning}></i>
                              <div className="droneInfoWarning pull-left">
                                <span>{notificationTime}</span>
                                <span className="weakSignal">{notification.message}</span>
                              </div>
                              <div className="read pull-right"></div>
                            </li>
                        );
                    }.bind(this));
                },

                mapLayerList: function() {
                    if(this.props.activeTab ==='dashboard' && this.context.router.getCurrentPathname()==='/') {
                        return <MapLayers ref="mapLayers" map={this.state.map} toggleFlightLayer={this.state.toggleFlightLayer}/>;
                    }
                },

                render: function() {
                    if(!this.access_token || !this.canAccess) {
                        return <div></div>;
                    }
                    var notificationList = this.getNotifications();
                    var activeTab = this.props.activeTab;
                    var userSessionData = SessionStore.getUserSession();
                    if(userSessionData) {
                        this.fullName = userSessionData.name || '';
                        this.userName =  this.fullName.substring(0,25);
                        this.email = userSessionData.email;
                    }
                    var legendMapLayers = this.mapLayerList();
                    var menuClass = this.getClassSet({
                        userProfileCmpny: true,
                        hide: !this.state.displayUserMenu
                    });
                    var toggleMenuClass = this.getClassSet({
                        userId: true,
                        clearfix: true,
                        active: this.state.toggleMenu
                    });
                    var adminCntClass = this.getClassSet({
                        adminMenu: true,
                        hide: !this.state.displayAdminMenu
                    });
                    var adminMenuClass = this.getClassSet({
                        adminMenuWrap: true,
                        clearfix: true,
                        toggleArrow: this.state.toggleAdminMenu,
                        active: activeTab === 'organization' || activeTab === 'geofence',
                        hide: !this.canAccessOrganizationManagement()
                    });
                    var notificationDropdownClass = this.getClassSet({
                        notificationList: true,
                        hide: !this.state.displayNotificationMenu
                    });
                    var notificationMenuClass = this.getClassSet({
                        notification: true,
                        hide: activeTab !== 'dashboard'
                    });
                    var footerClass = this.getClassSet({
                        secureFooter: true,
                        dashboardActive: activeTab === 'dashboard'  && this.context.router.getCurrentPathname()==='/'
                    });
                    var dashboardClass = this.getClassSet({
                        mainMenuLink: true,
                        active: activeTab === 'dashboard'
                    });
                    var airspaceClass = this.getClassSet({
                        mainMenuLink: true,
                        active: activeTab === 'airspace'
                    });
                    var dronesClass = this.getClassSet({
                        mainMenuLink: true,
                        active: activeTab === 'drone'
                    });
                    var reportsClass = this.getClassSet({
                        mainMenuLink: true,
                        active: activeTab === 'reports'
                    });
                    var geofenceClass = this.getClassSet({
                        active: activeTab === 'geofence',
                        hide: !this.canAccessGeofenceManagement()
                    });
                    var userMClass = this.getClassSet({
                        mainMenuLink: true,
                        active: activeTab === 'user',
                        hide: !this.canAccessUserManagement()
                    });
                    var organizationClass = this.getClassSet({
                        active: activeTab === 'organization',
                        hide: !this.canAccessOrganizationManagement()
                    });
                    var apiuserClass = this.getClassSet({
                        active: activeTab === 'user',
                        hide: !this.canAccessApiUserManagement()
                    });
                    var adminClass = this.getClassSet({
                        active: activeTab === 'organization' || activeTab === 'geofence',
                        hide: !this.canAccessOrganizationManagement()
                    });
                    var notificationCount = _.keys(this.state.notifications).length;
                    var notificationCountClass = this.getClassSet({
                        notifyCount: true,
                        hide: (!notificationCount)
                    });
                    var browserValidationClass = this.getClassSet({
                        upgradeBrowser: true,
                        hide: this.isValidIe()
                    });
                    var browserNotIe = this.getClassSet({
                        loggedInWrap: true,
                        hide: !this.isValidIe()
                    });
                    var year = new Date();
                    var currentYear = year.getFullYear();
                    var hideAPIDocumentationClass = this.getClassSet({
                        hide: this.canNotAccessApiDocumentation()
                    });

                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div className={browserValidationClass}>
                                <div className="upgradeheader nonSecureWrap">
                                    <div className="container">
                                        <h1>
                                            <a className="logo" href="/"></a>
                                        </h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="content container">
                                    <div className="upgradeImage">
                                        <img src="/assets/image/browserupdate.png" alt="Upgrade your browser"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h2>Oops!</h2>
                                        <span className="browserNotSupported"> Your browser is currently not supported.</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer.aspx" target="_blank">Click here</a>
                                        <span> to update your browser to higher level!</span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div onClick={this.resetDropdown} className={browserNotIe}>
                                <header>
                                    <div className="container">
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-xs-2 clearfix">
                                                <h1>
                                                    <a className="logo" href="/"></a>
                                                </h1>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul className="col-xs-7 mainNav clearfix">
                                                <li className={dashboardClass}>
                                                    <a href="/dashboard.html">Dashboard</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li className={airspaceClass}>
                                                    <a href="/flightReservation.html">Air Space</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li className={dronesClass}>
                                                    <a href="/droneManagement.html">Drones</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li className={userMClass}>
                                                    <a href="/userManagement.html">Users</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li className={reportsClass}>
                                                    <a href="/reportManagement.html">Reports</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li className={adminMenuClass} onClick={this.showAdminMenu}>
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                                        <span>Admin</span>
                                                        <i className="userMenuicon"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <ul className={adminCntClass}>
                                                        <li className={geofenceClass}>
                                                            <a href="/geofenceManagement.html">Geo-fences</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li className={organizationClass}>
                                                            <a href="/organizationManagement.html">Organizations</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li className={apiuserClass}>
                                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.goToApiUsers}>API Users</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div className="col-xs-3 clearfix">
                                                <div className={notificationMenuClass} onClick={this.showNotifications}>
                                                    <i className="icon-notify"></i>
                                                    <div className={notificationCountClass}>
                                                        <span className="notifyCnt">{notificationCount}</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className={notificationDropdownClass}>
                                                        <div className="heading">
                                                            <h4>Notifications</h4>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <ul className="notifyContent">
                                                            {notificationList}
                                                        </ul>
                                                        <div className="showMoreNotify hide">
                                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.gotoNotifications}>Show more Notifications</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className={toggleMenuClass} onClick={this.showMenu}>
                                                    <i className="icon-userDefault"></i>
                                                    <span title={this.fullName}>{this.userName}</span>
                                                    <a className="menuIconWrap" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                                        <i className="userMenuicon"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <ul className="userOptions hide">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Profile</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Account</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">Logout</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <div className={menuClass}>
                                                        <div className="userCmpnyName clearfix">
                                                            <span>{this.email}</span>
                                                            <div className="clearfix settingsWrap">
                                                                <a onClick={this.goToUserProfile} href="javascript:void(0);" className="baseBtn secondaryBtn transEffect pull-left">Profile</a>
                                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" className="pull-left primaryLink" onClick={this.logOutUser}>Logout</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </header>
                                {this.props.children}
                                <footer className={footerClass}>
                                    <div className="clearfix">
                                        {legendMapLayers}
                                        <div className="secureFooterWrap">
                                            <div className="copyrightWrap">
                                                <span className="copyright">&#169; LATAS {currentYear}. </span>
                                                <span className="rightsReserved">All rights reserved.</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul className="footerLinks">
                                                <li className="privacyPolicy">
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.gotoPrivacyPolicy}>Privacy Policy</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li className={hideAPIDocumentationClass}>
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.goToApiDoc}>API Documentation</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </footer>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
            });
            export {Header,latas};
```

I just want to know why the code is rendering empty page.

Comment: Any error in your JS console?

Comment: No, I don't have any error. Actually I am upgrading my react-router and react version to latest one.

Comment: You are using `IndexRedirect` but you are importing `IndexRoute`.

Comment: Can we see `header-view.js`? I suspect you are not rendering `this.props.children` in there

Comment: @juandemarco: that doesn't make sense because OP didn't use latas in DashBoardView Render function

Comment: On the contrary, it does make sense because he is using `Header` as the component for the `/` view, and therefore in order to render any child route the parent must render its children.

Comment: @juandemarco: I have added header view.

Comment: Does your `html` file have an tag with `wrapper` as id? You might have accidentally used class instead.

Comment: @Kujira: No that is not the case. I have wrapper as id only.